# HttpPost with multiple string type parameters. Why both parameters are null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an API controller as follows:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostData(string param1, string param2)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        string result = "result =  " + param1 + "." + param2;
        return new JsonResult(result );
    }
}
```

When I try to access this from postman, I use following in the json body when composing the post request.

```
{
    "param1" : "abc",
    "param2": "def"
}
```

However, this causes a 400 Bad Request. If I add a breakpoint on the `PostData` method, it's hitting the first line where I am doing a check on null or empty string and both the parameters are null. That leads me to think I am not properly constructing the json on the client side. Can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: 1. use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: `param1=abc&param2=def`  2. or create a DTO class `public class Dto{ public string Param1 {get;set;} public string Param2{get;set;} }` And change the method to `PostData(Dto payload)`

Comment: I don't want to use DTO classes and prefer to stick to work with json. Is this possible with the constraints?

Comment: If you have only one parameter, it is possible. However, it doesn't work for your scenario: JSON need deserialize the HTTP Body before binding the parameters

Comment: If you use javascript to post json data, you might need JSON.stringify(jsonObject)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
....
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public string GetStudentData_1(string p1, string p2)
    {
        return p1 + p2;
    }
}
```

This is how i called it

[image]

The second way is passing a `VALID` Json. Change your Controller method as:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public string GetStudentData_1([FromBody]JObject data)
{
    return data["p1"].ToString() + data["p2"].ToString() ;
}
```

And make sure JSON is valid, and you select `JSON (application/json)` in in Body/Raw:

[image]

`data["p1"]` and `data["p2"]` gives you access to the Parameters. Bring in the following reference for `JObject` and

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Comment: I don't like to pass it through query parameters. Will it be possible to change it to pass parametres through the body?

Comment: @BKS - use Raw.

Comment: that's what i am using and causing both parameters to be null in the API

Comment: @BKS - did you try the 2nd method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FormCollection` instead.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult PostData(FormCollection collection)
{
    // Get Post Params Here
    string p1 = collection["param1"];
    string p2 = collection["param2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[FromBody]**

```
public IActionResult PostData([FromBody]string param1, [FromBody]string param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use asp.net core 3.0,you could use `JsonElement` to receive your json:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData([FromBody]JsonElement data)
{
    var param = "";
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<dynamic>(data);
    using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json))
    {
        JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
        var param1 = root.GetProperty("param1");
        var param1data = param1.GetString();
        var param2 = root.GetProperty("param2");
        var param2data = param2.GetString();
        param = param1data + param2data;
    }
    return param;
}
```

@Sadique's answer could also work well.For asp.net core3.0,you need to do the following before using the code:

1.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

2.In `ConfigureServices()` add a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

3.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData([FromBody]JObject data)
{
    return data["param1"].ToString() + data["param2"].ToString();
}
```